# Right way to implement a reducer

Tags: angular, redux, reducers

I am writing some reducer logic in Angular 2 with Typescript and I have the following logic

```
const addOption = (state: Array<Poll>, id: number, payload: any) => {
    let pollToUpdate = {};

    state.map((poll) => {
        if(poll.poll_id == id) {
            pollToUpdate = poll;
        }
    }); 

    const newState = state.filter((elem) => {
        return elem.poll_id !== id;
    });

    pollToUpdate['options'].push(payload.new_option);

    return [...newState, Object.assign({}, pollToUpdate)];
}
```

Basically, I have an array of objects which are defined by the following interface in Angular 2

```
export interface Poll {
    poll_id: number, 
    options: Array<{name: string, votes: number}>, 
    voter_ids: Array<number>, 
    createdBy: string
}
```

And I am trying to add a new object into the options array. 
Here is the reducer call

```
const action = {
        type: 'ADD_OPTION', 
        payload: {
            poll_id: 1, 
            new_option: {name: 'option 3', votes: 0}
        }
    };

    const nextState = reducer(initialState, action);
```

Does the reducer logic count as "immutable". Am I implementing it the right way?

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider following moments with your approach.

1. Your reducer reorders poll list for no reason. It might be a problem if you say want to allow users to reorder polls or something
2. The very inner array `options` that was actually changed remains the same.

I'd make it like this

```
const addOption = (state: Array<Poll>, id: number, payload: any) => {
    return state.map(poll => {
       if(poll.poll_id === id) {
          return {...poll, options: poll.options.concat(payload.new_option)}
       }
       return poll
    })
}
```